# Well definedness of a map defined on a set of generators of a group G.

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Let $G$ be a group with a presentation $(S,R)$, where $S$ is the set of generators and $R$ is the set of relations. I want to define a map from $G$ to some group $H$. I know where elements of $S$ goes. So naturally I can extend to whole of $G$. How to check that the extended map is well defined?

Comment: This is what the relations are for: a necessary and sufficient condition is that the relations continue to be satisfied in $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well defined if and only if the images of the elements os $S$ satisfy the same relations $R$ as the group $G$ itself. So, for instance, if you have a single ralation $xy=y^2x$ and if your map is $f$, the equality $f(x)f(y)=f(y)^2f(x)$ must hold.

Comment: $G$ is actually free group on $S$ modulo the smallest normal closure of $R$ in $G$. That is $G=F(S)/<R>$. Let $f :S \rightarrow H$. Extend this to $F(S)$.Then define $\overline{f}: G \rightarrow H$ by $ \overline{f}(\overline{g})=f(g)$. To see $\overline{f}$ is well defined it is enough to check $\overline{f}$ vanishes on $<R>$ or enough to check images of $S$ satisfies all the relations. AM i right?

Comment: @AnupamAh Yes, you are.

Answer (score 3):

Let $G$ be the group $ \langle S | R \rangle $. Let $H$ be any group.
Given any map $S \to H$ given by $s \mapsto \bar{s}$, there exists a morphism $G \to H$ extending it if and only if
the relations of $R$ are satised by the elements $\bar{s}$, i.e. if for any word $r(s_1, . . . , s_m)$ in $R$, the product
$r_H(\bar{s}_1, . . . , \bar{s}_m)$ is trivial in $H$.

the proof is:
Denote by $\pi$ the morphism $F(S) \to G$ extending $S \to G$.
Suppose there exists a morphism $\phi : G \to H$ extending $s \mapsto \bar{s}$. Then
$r_H(\bar{s}_1, . . . , \bar{s}_m)=\phi (r_G(s_1, . . . , s_m))=\phi(1)=1$ 
since $\phi$ is a morphism.

For the other direction:
let φ : F(S) → H be the unique morphism extending $s \mapsto \bar{s}$. For any
$r(s_1, . . . , s_m) ∈ R$, we have that $φ(r(s_1, . . . , s_m)) = r_H(\bar{s}_1, . . . , \bar{s}_m) = 1$ by hypothesis. Thus Ker(φ)
contains $R$, and it is normal - it must thus contain $\langle \langle R \rangle \rangle = Ker(π)$. Hence φ factors through π i.e.
$φ = φ' \circ π$. The morphism $φ'
: G → H $ extends $s \mapsto \bar{s}$.